# AngularJS / NgMap - Zoom to selected pins and center

Tags: json, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-filter, ng-map

I have an SPA that is displaying pins on a map that are filtered down by Region, State/Province and ultimately City. I have Lat/Lng in my locations, and I'm passing that to the map markup and filtering it on each select list selection. I'm running in to issues with getting the map to focus on each region as it's subsequently filtered down.

Is there a way to recenter when using the markup to display the markers, or to do that would I need to rework the code to handle displaying the markers in the JS instead of the markup?

See Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qaLFYD?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute', 'angular.filter', 'ngMap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $anchorScroll, $location, $http) {


  // GET data
  $scope.dataObject = data.List;
  $scope.locationObject = data.Locations;



  $scope.cart = [];

  $scope.addToCart = function(index) {
    $scope.cart.push(index);
    $scope.cartCount = $scope.cart.length;
  }

  $scope.activeRow = function(index) {
    $scope.selectedRow = index;
    $location.hash();
    $anchorScroll('anchor-' + index);
  }

  $scope.gotoAnchor = function(x) {
    var newHash = 'anchor' + x;
  }

  $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, map) {
    map.setOptions({
      draggable: true
    });
  });





}).filter('byFilter', function() {
  return function(items, location) {
    var filtered = [];

    if (!location || !items.length) {
      return items;
    }

    items.forEach(function(itemElement, itemIndex) {
      itemElement.Locations.forEach(function(locationElement, locationIndex) {
        if (filterCountry(locationElement, location) || filterRegion(locationElement, location) || filterCity(locationElement, location))
          filtered.push(itemElement);
      });
    });

    return filtered;
  };

  function filterCountry(locationElement, location) {
    var exist = false;
    if (!location.Region) {
      exist = true;
      return exist;
    } else exist = (locationElement.Region === location.Region);
    return exist;
  }

  function filterRegion(locationElement, location) {
    var exist = false;
    if (!location.StateName) {
      exist = true;
      return exist;
    }
    locationElement.Sites.forEach(function(siteElement, siteIndex) {
      if (siteElement.State === location.StateName) {
        exist = true;
        return false;
      }
    });
    return exist;
  }

  function filterCity(locationElement, location) {
    var exist = false;
    if (!location.CityName) {
      exist = true;
      return exist;
    }

    locationElement.Sites.forEach(function(siteElement, siteIndex) {
      if (siteElement.City === location.CityName) {
        exist = true;
        return false;
      }
    });
    return exist;
  }
}).filter('ForMap', function() {
  return function(items, location) {
    var filtered = [];

    if (!items) {
      return items;
    }

    var state = (location.state ? location.state.StateName : '');
    var city = (location.city ? location.city.CityName : '');
    var region = (location.region ? location.region.Region : '');

    items.forEach(function(itemElement, itemIndex) {
      itemElement.Locations.forEach(function(locationElement, locationIndex) {
        if (locationElement.Region === region || !region) {
          locationElement.Sites.forEach(function(siteElement, siteIndex) {
            if ((siteElement.State == state && !city) || siteElement.City == city || (!state && !city)) {
              filtered.push(siteElement);
              return false;
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

body {
  background: #eee;
}
div.cart {
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
  background: silver;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.cart h1 {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.item-list-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.item-list-wrapper table td {
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.item-list {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #efefe4;
}
.col-num {
  width: 100px;
}
.col-compound {
  width: 80px;
}
.filters {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.filters select {
  width: 200px;
}
.filters column {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.filters select {
  display: inline-block;
}
.region {
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.state {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.map-wrapper {
  width: 490px;
  height: 490px;
}
map {
  width: 490px;
  height: 490px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-ui.min.css" />
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-messages.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.13.3" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.1/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-filter.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="ng-map.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-scroll.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="http://zbl.me/test/103015.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-view=""></div>
  <div class="filters">
    <h2>Filter results</h2>
    <column>
      <select name="selectRegion" class="form-control" ng-model="selectRegion" ng-options="location as location.Region for location in locationObject | orderBy: location.Region:reverse">
        <option value="">Select Region</option>
      </select>

      <select name="selectState" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!selectRegion" ng-model="selectState" ng-options="state as state.StateName for state in selectRegion.States">
        <option value="">Select State/Province/Country</option>
      </select>

      <select name="selectCity" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!selectState" ng-model="selectCity" ng-options="city as city.CityName for city in selectState.Cities">
        <option value="">Select City</option>
      </select>
    </column>
    <column>
      <select name="selectPhase" class="form-control" ng-model="selectPhase" ng-options="data.Phase as data.Phase for data in dataObject | unique: 'Phase' | orderBy: 'Phase' ">
        <option value="">Select Phase</option>
      </select>
      <select name="selectNumber" class="form-control" ng-model="selectNumber" ng-options="data.Number as data.Number for data in dataObject | unique: 'Compound' | orderBy: 'Compound' ">
        <option value="">Select Number</option>
      </select>
    </column>
  </div>

  <div map-lazy-load="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js">
    <map zoom="1" scrollwheel="false">
      <span ng-repeat="site in (dataObject | ForMap : {region:selectRegion, state:selectState, city:selectCity}) track by $index" id="{{data.Id}}">
    <marker position="[{{site.Latitude}},{{site.Longitude}}]"></marker>
</span>
    </map>
  </div>


  <div class="cart">
    <h1>Cart: {{cartCount}}</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="item-list-wrapper">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
      <tr ng-repeat="data in dataObject | byFilter | filterBy:['Phase']: selectPhase | filterBy:['Number']: selectNumber track by $index" ng-click="activeRow($index)">
        <td class="column">{{data.Phase}}</td>
        <td class="column col-num">{{data.Number}}</td>
        <td class="column col-compound">{{data.Compound}}</td>
        <td>
          <span ng-repeat="location in data.Locations track by $index" class="region">{{ location.Region}}: 
                                <span ng-repeat="site in location.Sites | unique: 'State'" class="state">{{site.State}}
                                </span>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td><a href="" ng-click="addToCart()">Add</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like adding zoom-to-include-markers="true" to the map element achieves this.

```html
         <div map-lazy-load="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js">
          <map zoom="1" scrollwheel="false" zoom-to-include-markers="auto">
  <span ng-repeat="site in (dataObject | ForMap : {region:selectRegion, state:selectState, city:selectCity}) track by $index" id="{{data.Id}}">
    <marker position="[{{site.Latitude}},{{site.Longitude}}]"></marker>
</span>
          </map>
  </div>
```